# Shiny DT combining color grouping and foreground color coding

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to merge two features which apparently do not go well together.

From what I understood playing with this, either you can control the style of a specific column using `formatStyle` (by passing a datatable object) or you can play with the container, control the columns header and consider added options (which works very well). I can't manage to do both. Ideally I would like to find a way to color code a column in the second version of what is provided.

In this simple example you can appreciate what I mean:

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)

df <- data.frame(col1 = c("A", "B", "C", "D"),
                 col2 = c("aa", "bb", "cc", "dd"),
                 col3 = c(-1, 0, 1, 2),
                 stringsAsFactors = F)

ui <- fluidPage(h4("Version 1: color coded column"),
                DTOutput("table1"),
                br(),
                h4("Version 2: grouped columns"),
                DTOutput("table2"))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  ### V1 - format style ##########################
  output$table1 <- renderDataTable({
    datatable(df) %>%
      formatStyle(columns = 3,
                  color = styleInterval(cuts = 0, values = c("red", "green")),
                  fontWeight = "bold")})

  ### V2 - container group cols ##################
  output$table2 <- renderDataTable(df, 
                                  container = htmltools::withTags(table(
                                    class = 'display',
                                    thead(
                                      tr(
                                        th(colspan = 2, 'Group 1'),
                                        th(colspan = 1, 'Group 2')),
                                      tr(
                                        lapply(c('Column 1', 'Column 2', 'Values'), th))))),
                                  options = list(pageLength = 10, autoWidth = TRUE),
                                  rownames = FALSE,
                                  filter= "bottom")
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The output is [image: Results]

**EDIT**

While the answer below goes deep into the essence of what can be done, it is also true there is a simple solution based on the code provided above. While I was trying to find it, I was sidetracked by the mistake of placing the *container* statement outside the `datatable()` function.

A working code would then be:

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)

df <- data.frame(col1 = c("A", "B", "C", "D"),
                 col2 = c("aa", "bb", "cc", "dd"),
                 col3 = c(-1, 0, 1, 2),
                 stringsAsFactors = F)

ui <- fluidPage(h4("All in!"),
                DTOutput("table"))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  ### V1 - format style ##########################
  output$table <- renderDataTable({
    datatable(df,
              container = htmltools::withTags(table(
                class = 'display',
                thead(
                  tr(
                    th(colspan = 2, 'Group 1'),
                    th(colspan = 1, 'Group 2')),
                  tr(
                    lapply(c('Column 1', 'Column 2', 'Values'), th))))),
              options = list(pageLength = 10, autoWidth = TRUE),
              rownames = FALSE,
              filter= "bottom") %>%
      formatStyle(columns = 3,
                  color = styleInterval(cuts = 0, values = c("red", "green")),
                  fontWeight = "bold")},
  )
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Thanks all!

Comment: What's the problem with `formatStyle` for the grouped columns? For me it works perfectly.

Comment: That is also true: my mistake in that respect was to apply the *container* bit outside the `datatable()` bit. I will update the post, clarifying this. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### option1: format the cells with HTML before making the datatable:

```r
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)

df <- data.frame(col1 = c("A", "B", "C", "D"),
                 col2 = c("aa", "bb", "cc", "dd"),
                 col3 = c(-1, 0, 1, 2),
                 stringsAsFactors = F)

df <- mutate(df, col3 = if_else(
    col3 <=0, 
    paste0("<b style='color: red; float: right;'>", col3, "</b>"),
    paste0("<b style='color: green; float: right;'>", col3, "</b>")
))
ui <- fluidPage(h4("Version 2: grouped columns"), DTOutput("table2"))

server <- function(input, output, session) {

    ### V2 - container group cols ##################
    output$table2 <- renderDataTable(df, 
                                     container = htmltools::withTags(table(
                                         class = 'display',
                                         thead(
                                             tr(
                                                 th(colspan = 2, 'Group 1'),
                                                 th(colspan = 1, 'Group 2')),
                                             tr(
                                                 lapply(c('Column 1', 'Column 2', 'Values'), th))))),
                                     options = list(pageLength = 10, autoWidth = TRUE),
                                     rownames = FALSE,
                                     escape = FALSE,
                                     filter= "bottom")
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The key is to add `escape = FALSE` argument.

#### option 2: use datatable callbacks

This requires you to know javascript and advanced CSS selectors.

```r
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)

df <- data.frame(col1 = c("A", "B", "C", "D"),
                 col2 = c("aa", "bb", "cc", "dd"),
                 col3 = c(-1, 0, 1, 2),
                 stringsAsFactors = F)



ui <- fluidPage(h4("Version 2: grouped columns"), DTOutput("table2"))
server <- function(input, output, session) {

    ### V2 - container group cols ##################
    output$table2 <- renderDataTable(
        datatable(
            df,
            container = htmltools::withTags(table(
                class = 'display',
                thead(
                    tr(
                        th(colspan = 2, 'Group 1'),
                        th(colspan = 1, 'Group 2')),
                    tr(
                        lapply(c('Column 1', 'Column 2', 'Values'), th))))),
            options = list(
                pageLength = 10, 
                autoWidth = TRUE,
                rowCallback = JS(
                "function(row, data, displayNum, displayIndex, dataIndex) {
                    var value=data[2]; 
                    $(row).find('td:nth-of-type(3)').css({
                        'font-weight':'bold',
                        'color':isNaN(parseFloat(value)) ? '' : value <= 0 ? \"red\" : \"green\"
                    });
                }"
                )
            ),
            rownames = FALSE,
            filter= "bottom"
        )
   )
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Note

1. `data[2]`, here `2` is the column `index - 1`. For example, here you want to format the third column, so you have `3 -1 = 2`. Javascript is 0 indexed, but R is 1 indexed. You need to do the conversion.
2. `nth-of-type(3)` is cell index in CSS. In this case, the cell index number is the same as the column index in R. Here it means to select the third cell in this row.

#### Comparision

option1 is called server-side processing, option2 is client-side processing.

- server-side: process the data on the computer where you host your shiny apps.
- client-side: process is done on the computer where users open up the browser.

Imagine you have a table with millions of records, and you have many many users open up the app at the same time. Your server needs to process this formatting for all users. Processing this amount of data is not like milliseconds we have here, maybe a few seconds, and this many users' processing time will sum up. Your server will be overloaded.

If you use the client-side processing, the data will be sent to users as it is, then their browser is responsible to do the formatting to it reduces your server work. However, if the user has a potato computer (poor performing), it may take them a long time to process on their own.

[image]

Comment: As good as an answer as I could have possibly hoped for. Thank you!

Comment: Question if I may. The solution devised in the edited post is client-side or server-side? I suspect the former (datatable is a JS implementation if I remember correctly), but I'd like to make sure.

Comment: client-side. `formatStyle` actually uses callbacks with R wrappers, easier for people who don't have much knowledge about js to use.